# What did Rina know about the "legendary cosplayer" Alice's true identity?

Tags: photo-kano

In episode 11 of Photokano, the "legendary cosplayer" Alice helps Rina during the culture festival. At that time, it's clear that Rina knows something about Alice, very likely her true identity. However, Alice tells her to keep it a secret.

What did Rina know about who Alice is?

[image]

Comment: Seeing how Rina can "see" the stealth girl (= Alice), I am not surprise that she can see through the cosplay...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rina knew that Alice's true identity is Uchida Yuuko.

Earlier in the same episode, Rina sees through Yuuko's stealth ability and invites her to try some cooking. She eventually agrees and seems to have fun.

[image: Rina and Yuuko having fun making a cake]

During the school festival, Rina once again sees through the cosplayer Alice's "stealth" ability of masking her true identity. In a low voice, extremely similar to Yuuko's normal voice, Alice simply tells Rina to keep it a secret.

In a previous episode, Maeda Kazuya also noticed a similarity between Yuuko and Alice but he thought it was just his imagination, so he didn't give it any further thought.

This may seem like speculation, but fortunately the episode's credits back it up.

[image: Screenshot of ending credits listing "Uchida Yuuko (Alice)"]

The line I've highlighted says this:

> Uchida Yuuko (Alice)     Takagaki Ayahi

So it seems like Rina is not only very good at noticing the people who tend to just be "background noise" to everyone else, but she can also easily see through the "disguise" of a costume and different personality to see who someone really is. Both are pretty great abilities if you ask me.